# Overriding VPN configuration to access external websites

Tags: vpn, dns, routing

I'm going to break down the problem into sections to make it easier to understand.

##### The Problem

I work for a client which requires us to use an Ivanti VPN in order to access their servers and internal tooling websites such as Gitlab, Nexus, etc. Whenever we connect to the VPN using the Ivanti software, we are then unable to access the broader internet. This means that in order to be able to work normally, we must setup a VM with the VPN access and utilize the host for all non-intranet related activities. I want to be able to overcome this limitation.

##### Gathering Information

Let me start by saying that networking isn't my strong suit.
Since our company laptops run on Windows 10/11, one of the first things I checked were the network adapters, specifically the one created by Ivanti. I noticed that it sets the adapter IP to a `10.XX.XX.XX` with a subnet mask of `255.255.255.255`, as well as two different `10.X` DNS servers.
I then performed some troubleshooting by running `ipconfig /all`, `route print`, and `nslookup` with and without the VPN active. What I discovered was the following:

- Starting up the VPN made the DNS defined on Ivanti's network adapter the default
- It added 3-4 entries in the route table

##### Attempting Workarounds

The first thing that came to mind was toying with the routing table using `route ADD`, `route DELETE`, and `route CHANGE`. By finding out, for example, the IP of `example.com` and adding a specific rule so that traffic to that IP goes through my WiFi interface I was able to successfully ping it even with the VPN on. But the issue still remained - I couldn't access the broader internet since my browser will have to go through the DNS regardless.
I then came accross [Add-DnsClientNrptRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/add-dnsclientnrptrule?view=windowsserver2022-ps) which is a powershell command that enabled me to basically enforce namespaces to go through specific nameservers. This actually worked and I was able to whitelist some websites and access them through my own DNS, but what I wanted to do was, in fact, the opposite of this. It would be best to have full internet access, and be able to simply force the internal websites to go through the client's DNS. I also noticed that, for some reason, some websites were not reachable. I believe this had to do with the fact that Ipv6 was being used to access most of them, and the ones on IPv4 were being routed through the incorrect DNS.

I'm writing this to see if anyone has any ideas as to if it's possible to even achieve what I'm attempting to do. Any other ideas are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to set the appropriate routes in your routing table.

Comment: You will also have to request the VPN server configuration be changed, to allow those websites what you describe seems intentionally configured

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have all the elements for the solution available. You only need to think the other way around: default is Internet, specific is the VPN gateway.

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 gateway <Wlan Default Gateway> interface <Wlan Address> 
route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 gateway <gateway of the VPN> interface <VPN address>
```

The same goes for DNS: use 8.8.8.8 as default and add a specific 10.x.x.x server with `Add-DnsClientNrptRule`.

Note that some companies have a policy that, if you are connected to their network, you must use their proxy. Be sure that you do not violate your client's policies!

Comment: Just seconding the statement about possible violation of company policy by allowing split tunneling from WAN through VPN, and causing security issues. Check carefully before implementing any solution!

Comment: Can you elaborate on using the 8.8.8.8 DNS as default? I've tried the steps mentioned, and managed to open specific pages on firefox that were being loaded via ipv6. Because the VPN doesn't use ipv6, all ipv6 connections are successful after those commands, but ipv4 connections still do not work. Any idea?

Comment: Add the output of `netstat -rn` to the question. If your system can resolve on the google DNS server 8.8.8.8, you have IPv4 access to the Internet.